# Json data to javaScript Treeview

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, treeview

hello there is a json data as below.

```
    var arr = [{
                "ID": 1,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(403) 125-2552",
                "City": "Coevorden",
                "Name": "Grady"
            }, {
                "ID": 2,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(979) 486-1932",
                "City": "Chełm",
                "Name": "Scarlet"
            }, {
                "ID": 3,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(573) 685-8350",
                "City": "Wardha",
                "Name": "Adria"
            }, {
                "ID": 4,
                "parentID": 3,
                "Phone": "(630) 292-9737",
                "City": "Villers-la-Loue",
                "Name": "Xerxes"
            }, {
                "ID": 5,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(755) 968-6539",
                "City": "Gönen",
                "Name": "Madeson"
            }, {
                "ID": 6,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(644) 892-5485",
                "City": "Timkur",
                "Name": "Rae"
            }, {
                "ID": 7,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(896) 297-6568",
                "City": "Louvain-la-Neuve",
                "Name": "Celeste"
            }, {
                "ID": 8,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(168) 452-3538",
                "City": "Worksop",
                "Name": "Rowan"
            }, {
                "ID": 9,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(873) 337-9560",
                "City": "Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler",
                "Name": "Kendall"
            }, {
                "ID": 10,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(450) 579-0491",
                "City": "MIDdelburg",
                "Name": "Madaline"
            }, {
                "ID": 11,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(111) 162-2502",
                "City": "Birecik",
                "Name": "Chandler"
            }, {
                "ID": 12,
                "parentID": 8,
                "Phone": "(712) 483-3905",
                "City": "Courbevoie",
                "Name": "Craig"
            }, {
                "ID": 13,
                "parentID": 8,
                "Phone": "(872) 499-5833",
                "City": "Cuccaro Vetere",
                "Name": "Basia"
            }, {
                "ID": 14,
                "parentID": 6,
                "Phone": "(724) 797-0077",
                "City": "Portree",
                "Name": "Elmo"
            }, {
                "ID": 15,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(366) 967-0433",
                "City": "Dublin",
                "Name": "Cairo"
            }, {
                "ID": 16,
                "parentID": 11,
                "Phone": "(147) 708-7321",
                "City": "Rivière-du-Loup",
                "Name": "Mannix"
            }, {
                "ID": 17,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(407) 519-9894",
                "City": "Roubaix",
                "Name": "Justine"
            }]
.
.
.
```

I wanted to make a treeview of this data and I got a result like the one below. No problem, it works properly.

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "parentID": 0,
        "Phone": "(403) 125-2552",
        "City": "Coevorden",
        "Name": "Grady"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "parentID": 0,
        "Phone": "(979) 486-1932",
        "City": "Chełm",
        "Name": "Scarlet",
        "children": [
            {
                "ID": 30,
                "parentID": 2,
                "Phone": "(641) 756-7073",
                "City": "Harrison Hot Springs",
                "Name": "Hamilton",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "ID": 54,
                        "parentID": 30,
                        "Phone": "(800) 876-5942",
                        "City": "Ribnitz-Damgarten",
                        "Name": "Kelsie",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "ID": 62,
                                "parentID": 54,
                                "Phone": "(523) 159-2911",
                                "City": "Biała Podlaska",
                                "Name": "Clio"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 87,
                        "parentID": 30,
                        "Phone": "(500) 895-9220",
                        "City": "Piracicaba",
                        "Name": "Maya"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": 40,
                "parentID": 2,
                "Phone": "(921) 336-7339",
                "City": "Namur",
                "Name": "Lionel"
            },
            {
                "ID": 43,
                "parentID": 2,
                "Phone": "(410) 695-8540",
                "City": "Saint-Laurent",
                "Name": "Deanna",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "ID": 63,
                        "parentID": 43,
                        "Phone": "(475) 190-5102",
                        "City": "Nicoya",
                        "Name": "Nola"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 98,
                        "parentID": 43,
                        "Phone": "(268) 572-5059",
                        "City": "San Marcello Pistoiese",
                        "Name": "Marny"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "parentID": 0,
        "Phone": "(573) 685-8350",
        "City": "Wardha",
        "Name": "Adria",
        "children": [
            {
                "ID": 4,
                "parentID": 3,
                "Phone": "(630) 292-9737",
                "City": "Villers-la-Loue",
                "Name": "Xerxes",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "ID": 44,
                        "parentID": 4,
                        "Phone": "(287) 866-8953",
                        "City": "Fiuminata",
                        "Name": "Darius",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "ID": 47,
                                "parentID": 44,
                                "Phone": "(779) 411-0381",
                                "City": "Pontedera",
                                "Name": "Harding",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "ID": 92,
                                        "parentID": 47,
                                        "Phone": "(925) 263-0254",
                                        "City": "Curacaví",
                                        "Name": "Aristotle"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 56,
                        "parentID": 4,
                        "Phone": "(963) 719-2718",
                        "City": "Gore",
                        "Name": "Rafael"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": 58,
                "parentID": 3,
                "Phone": "(464) 318-7548",
                "City": "Curepto",
                "Name": "Leila"
            }
        ]
    .
    .
    .
```

My main question is parentID: I don't want to write parentID to objects that write 0. But when I remove the places that say parentID: 0, it doesn't work properly. Can you help?

The code I run is:

```
tree = function(array) {
        var o = {
            ID: 0
        }

        function arrGet(o) {
            if (Array.isArray(o.children)) {
                o.children.forEach(arrGet);
            }
        }
        array.forEach(function(a) {
            o[a.ID] = o[a.ID] || {
                ID: a.ID,
                parentID: a.parentID,
                Phone: a.Phone,
                City: a.City,
                Name: a.Name
            };
            a.children = o[a.ID].children;
            o[a.parentID] = o[a.parentID] || {
                ID: a.parentID
            };
            o[a.parentID].children = o[a.parentID].children || [];
            o[a.parentID].children.push(o[a.ID]);
        });
        arrGet(o[0]);
        return o[0].children;
    }(arr);
document.writeln('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just find the way inside the tree, based on origin array...

## Full code:

```js
/*--------------------------------------------------------*\
|  treeMaker  : JSON [Array of obj] to Treeview (function) |
|                                                          |
|   input array objets must be like { ID,[ parentID ] ...} |
\* -------------------------------------------------------*/

const treeMaker = arr =>
  arr.reduce((tree,{parentID,...useful},_,Origin)=>
  {
  if (!parentID) tree.push({...useful})                          // direct case!
  else
    {
    let path = { children: tree }                             // path for insert
      , road = [ Origin.find(x=>x.ID===parentID) ]      // every road has an end
      ;
    while(!!road[0].parentID)            // as long as a parentID property exist
      {
      road.unshift(Origin.find(x=>x.ID===road[0].parentID))   // get road origin
      }
    for(let way of road)                  // make your way by following the road
      {
      path = path.children.find(x=>x.ID===way.ID) // change the path to children
      }
    if (!path.children) path.children = []   // if not exist, add children array
      ;
    path.children.push({...useful})                     // copy all useful items
    }
  return tree                                              // back to the trees!
  },[])
  
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/

// test part
const myArr = 
    [ { ID:  1,               Phone: '(403) 125-2552', City: 'Coevorden',              Name: 'Grady'    } 
    , { ID:  2,               Phone: '(979) 486-1932', City: 'Chełm',                  Name: 'Scarlet'  } 
    , { ID:  3,               Phone: '(573) 685-8350', City: 'Wardha',                 Name: 'Adria'    } 
    , { ID:  4, parentID:  3, Phone: '(630) 292-9737', City: 'Villers-la-Loue',        Name: 'Xerxes'   } 
    , { ID:  5,               Phone: '(755) 968-6539', City: 'Gönen',                  Name: 'Madeson'  } 
    , { ID:  6, parentID:  5, Phone: '(644) 892-5485', City: 'Timkur',                 Name: 'Rae'      } 
    , { ID:  7,               Phone: '(896) 297-6568', City: 'Louvain-la-Neuve',       Name: 'Celeste'  } 
    , { ID:  8, parentID:  5, Phone: '(168) 452-3538', City: 'Worksop',                Name: 'Rowan'    } 
    , { ID:  9, parentID:  5, Phone: '(873) 337-9560', City: 'Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler', Name: 'Kendall'  } 
    , { ID: 10,               Phone: '(450) 579-0491', City: 'MIDdelburg',             Name: 'Madaline' } 
    , { ID: 11,               Phone: '(111) 162-2502', City: 'Birecik',                Name: 'Chandler' } 
    , { ID: 12, parentID:  8, Phone: '(712) 483-3905', City: 'Courbevoie',             Name: 'Craig'    } 
    , { ID: 13, parentID:  8, Phone: '(872) 499-5833', City: 'Cuccaro Vetere',         Name: 'Basia'    } 
    , { ID: 14, parentID:  6, Phone: '(724) 797-0077', City: 'Portree',                Name: 'Elmo'     } 
    , { ID: 15, parentID:  5, Phone: '(366) 967-0433', City: 'Dublin',                 Name: 'Cairo'    } 
    , { ID: 16, parentID: 11, Phone: '(147) 708-7321', City: 'Rivière-du-Loup',        Name: 'Mannix'   } 
    , { ID: 17,               Phone: '(407) 519-9894', City: 'Roubaix',                Name: 'Justine'  } 
    , { ID: 18, parentID: 14, Phone: '(938) 793-5446', City: 'Eugene',                 Name: 'Dahlia'   } 
    , { ID: 19, parentID:  5, Phone: '(425) 682-2189', City: 'Salisbury',              Name: 'Irene'    } 
    , { ID: 20, parentID: 12, Phone: '(351) 187-8200', City: 'Garaguso',               Name: 'Trevor'   } 
    , { ID: 21,               Phone: '(601) 944-5214', City: 'Pointe-au-Pic',          Name: 'Iris'     } 
    , { ID: 22, parentID: 20, Phone: '(479) 532-6127', City: 'Salt Lake City',         Name: 'Fleur'    } 
    , { ID: 23, parentID: 19, Phone: '(339) 973-1695', City: 'Meldert',                Name: 'Hayley'   } 
    , { ID: 24, parentID: 11, Phone: '(946) 766-1649', City: 'Corral',                 Name: 'Baker'    } 
    , { ID: 25,               Phone: '(964) 413-7033', City: 'Joliet',                 Name: 'Leo'      } 
    , { ID: 26, parentID:  7, Phone: '(898) 476-0059', City: 'Burntisland',            Name: 'Rigel'    } 
    ] 

const myTree = treeMaker ( myArr )

document.write('<pre>myTree:\n')
document.write(JSON.stringify(myTree,0,2))
document.write('</pre>')
```

In this algorithm, the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is used on each element of the original table, as follows:

```js
let element1 = { ID:6, parentID:5, City:'Timkur', Name:'Rae' }

let {parentID, ...useful} = element1 // destructuring assignment

console.log( parentID ) // return 5
console.log( useful )  // return  object { ID:6, City:'Timkur', Name:'Rae' }

console.log ( !parentID ) // return false
```

without parentID property:

```js
let element2 = { ID:7, City:'Louvain-la-Neuve', Name: 'Celeste' }

let {parentID, ...useful} = element2   // destructuring assignment

console.log( parentID ) // undefined
console.log( useful )  // return  object { ID:7, ....

console.log ( !parentID ) // return true
```

In this code the destructuring assignment is directly used inside the argument list of the array method `reduce` (see further)

*About the use of the Array.reduce method* ([see mdn for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)):
`const arr_tree = arr.reduce(function(tree,curr,idx,Origin) {…}, initilial_tree);`
*same as arrow notation:*
**a)** `const arr_tree = arr.reduce((tree,curr,_,Origin)=>{…}, []);`
**b)** `const arr_tree = arr.reduce((tree,{parentID,...useful},_,Origin)=>`

Arrguments:

1. `tree`, array under construction (initialized by `initilial_tree`, here=`[]` =>empty array), this element must be returned at each iteration
2. `curr`: the current element (as in a loop on the array), **used in an destructuring assignment
   {parentID,...useful} = curr ( please compare **a)** and **b)** )
3. `idx`: the index of the element (curr) on the array (not useful here and replaced by `_`)
4. `Origin`: the original table used by the method

> the algorithm:

for any element with a parentID, its parent must be found in the tree under construction.

That is, for an X element with a parentID there is an X-1 element with that ID.
And if this X-1 element has itself a ParentID, there is also another X-2 element with this ID.
And so on, until we find an X-n element that has no ParentID.

This X-N element is directly at the root of the result array.

All that remains is to follow the reverse path in the tree structure under construction:
we look for the position Xn at the level of its root, then on this one the element X- (n-1) among its children, until finding that of the element X-1 where we can add the element X in the list of its children.
Making sure to add an empty list of children, if X-1 had no children yet.

### There are therefore 2 parts:

> **1-** go up the road from X-1 to the X-n elements using the origin table

```js
let road = [ Origin.find(x=>x.ID===parentID) ]      // every road has an end

while(!!road[0].parentID)             // as long as a parentID property exist
  {
  road.unshift(Origin.find(x=>x.ID===road[0].parentID))    // get road origin
  }
```

if we start from element X = `{ ID: 12, parentID: 8, ... Name: 'Craig'}` (where the `parentID` value is **8**)
the result is :

```js
road = [ { ID: 5, ...             Name: 'Madeson' }
       , { ID: 8, parentID: 5,... Name: 'Rowan'   }
       ]
```

*note 1:*
the use of the `array.unshift()` method to add the elements from the top
/ unlike the `array.push()` method, the last element entered is therefore in position zero,
which allows the test to be passed
`(!!road[0].parentID)`
with always an index value at zero.
...*For the double exclamation mark [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)*

*note 2:*
the road array only contains "pointers" to the objects of the original array.

> **2-** find the path of element X-1 in tree structure under construction

```js
let path = { children: tree }                             // path for insert

for(let way of road)                  // make your way by following the road
  {
  path = path.children.find(x=>x.ID===way.ID) // change the path to children
  }
```

*note X:* I use my sort of [Whitesmiths style code formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) for years

**for info, it's look like that:**

```
├─1_Grady     
├─2_Scarlet   
├─3_Adria─┐    
│         └─4_Xerxes
├─5_Madeson─┐  
│           ├─6_Rae─┐      
│           │       └─14_Elmo─┐     
│           │                 └─18_Dahlia
│           ├─8_Rowan─┐    
│           │         ├─12_Craig─┐    
│           │         │          └─20_Trevor─┐   
│           │         │                      └─22_Fleur
│           │         └─13_Basia
│           ├─9_Kendall   
│           ├─15_Cairo     
│           └─19_Irene─┐    
│                      └─23_Hayley
├─7_Celeste─┐  
│           └─26_Rigel
├─10_Madaline  
├─11_Chandler─┐ 
│             ├─16_Mannix    
│             └─24_Baker
├─17_Justine   
├─21_Iris      
└─25_Leo
```

Comment: I was sick, I couldn't turn the computer on now I see

Comment: This works for me, I'll try it. Can you help me where I don't understand? Thank you.

Comment: @CanMuhammedKELEK of course, I will do my best to answer any of your questions regarding this code

Comment: @CanMuhammedKELEK  I completed my answer and add comments in my code

Comment: @CanMuhammedKELEK  I was able to improve and simplify this algorithm. The principle is the same, but it forced me to correct my explanations

Comment: I understood the code, I want to print it on the screen by using template literals, it takes the main objects, but the child objects are printing as object Object on the screen. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: @CanMuhammedKELEK I not really understood what you mean, but I have updated this by using `document.write` method, as your initial code. I also put this code  in a `function` (ie: treeMaker ). Is that what you are lookiing for ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the `delete` operator when `parentID` is equal to 0. This will delete the property from the object, hence not displaying it.

```js
var arr = [{
                "ID": 1,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(403) 125-2552",
                "City": "Coevorden",
                "Name": "Grady"
            }, {
                "ID": 2,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(979) 486-1932",
                "City": "Chełm",
                "Name": "Scarlet"
            }, {
                "ID": 3,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(573) 685-8350",
                "City": "Wardha",
                "Name": "Adria"
            }, {
                "ID": 4,
                "parentID": 3,
                "Phone": "(630) 292-9737",
                "City": "Villers-la-Loue",
                "Name": "Xerxes"
            }, {
                "ID": 5,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(755) 968-6539",
                "City": "Gönen",
                "Name": "Madeson"
            }, {
                "ID": 6,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(644) 892-5485",
                "City": "Timkur",
                "Name": "Rae"
            }, {
                "ID": 7,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(896) 297-6568",
                "City": "Louvain-la-Neuve",
                "Name": "Celeste"
            }, {
                "ID": 8,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(168) 452-3538",
                "City": "Worksop",
                "Name": "Rowan"
            }, {
                "ID": 9,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(873) 337-9560",
                "City": "Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler",
                "Name": "Kendall"
            }, {
                "ID": 10,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(450) 579-0491",
                "City": "MIDdelburg",
                "Name": "Madaline"
            }, {
                "ID": 11,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(111) 162-2502",
                "City": "Birecik",
                "Name": "Chandler"
            }, {
                "ID": 12,
                "parentID": 8,
                "Phone": "(712) 483-3905",
                "City": "Courbevoie",
                "Name": "Craig"
            }, {
                "ID": 13,
                "parentID": 8,
                "Phone": "(872) 499-5833",
                "City": "Cuccaro Vetere",
                "Name": "Basia"
            }, {
                "ID": 14,
                "parentID": 6,
                "Phone": "(724) 797-0077",
                "City": "Portree",
                "Name": "Elmo"
            }, {
                "ID": 15,
                "parentID": 5,
                "Phone": "(366) 967-0433",
                "City": "Dublin",
                "Name": "Cairo"
            }, {
                "ID": 16,
                "parentID": 11,
                "Phone": "(147) 708-7321",
                "City": "Rivière-du-Loup",
                "Name": "Mannix"
            }, {
                "ID": 17,
                "parentID": 0,
                "Phone": "(407) 519-9894",
                "City": "Roubaix",
                "Name": "Justine"
            }];
            
tree = function(array) {
        var o = {
            ID: 0
        }

        function arrGet(o) {
            if (Array.isArray(o.children)) {
                o.children.forEach(arrGet);
            }
        }
        array.forEach(function(a) {

            o[a.ID] = o[a.ID] || {
                ID: a.ID,
                parentID: a.parentID,
                Phone: a.Phone,
                City: a.City,
                Name: a.Name
            };
            
            if(a.parentID === 0) 
              delete o[a.ID].parentID;
              
            a.children = o[a.ID].children;
            o[a.parentID] = o[a.parentID] || {
                ID: a.parentID
            };
            o[a.parentID].children = o[a.parentID].children || [];
            o[a.parentID].children.push(o[a.ID]);
        });
        arrGet(o[0]);
        return o[0].children;
    }(arr);
document.writeln('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: True, but in the original data sent to me, the parentID was missing: 0. I added 0 to objects that do not have a parentID to run. They said it wouldn't be like this

Comment: but if you want to delete why do you add it in the first place? you can just add a null-check to avoid to access the field when it is not present

Comment: You are right, I knew how to do it this way, it was not accepted. I added the sample of the original version below

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Phone": "(403) 125-2552",
        "City": "Coevorden",
        "Name": "Grady"
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Phone": "(979) 486-1932",
        "City": "Chełm",
        "Name": "Scarlet"
    }, {
        "ID": 3,
        "Phone": "(573) 685-8350",
        "City": "Wardha",
        "Name": "Adria"
    }, {
        "ID": 4,
        "parentID": 3,
        "Phone": "(630) 292-9737",
        "City": "Villers-la-Loue",
        "Name": "Xerxes"
    }, {
        "ID": 5,
        "Phone": "(755) 968-6539",
        "City": "Gönen",
        "Name": "Madeson"
    }, {
        "ID": 6,
        "parentID": 5,
        "Phone": "(644) 892-5485",
        "City": "Timkur",
        "Name": "Rae"
    }, {
        "ID": 7,
        "Phone": "(896) 297-6568",
        "City": "Louvain-la-Neuve",
        "Name": "Celeste"
    }, {
        "ID": 8,
        "parentID": 5,
        "Phone": "(168) 452-3538",
        "City": "Worksop",
        "Name": "Rowan"
    }, {
        "ID": 9,
        "parentID": 5,
        "Phone": "(873) 337-9560",
        "City": "Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler",
        "Name": "Kendall"
    }, {
        "ID": 10,
        "Phone": "(450) 579-0491",
        "City": "MIDdelburg",
        "Name": "Madaline"
    }, {
        "ID": 11,
        "Phone": "(111) 162-2502",
        "City": "Birecik",
        "Name": "Chandler"
    }, {
        "ID": 12,
        "parentID": 8,
        "Phone": "(712) 483-3905",
        "City": "Courbevoie",
        "Name": "Craig"
    }, {
        "ID": 13,
        "parentID": 8,
        "Phone": "(872) 499-5833",
        "City": "Cuccaro Vetere",
        "Name": "Basia"
    }, {
        "ID": 14,
        "parentID": 6,
        "Phone": "(724) 797-0077",
        "City": "Portree",
        "Name": "Elmo"
    }, {
        "ID": 15,
        "parentID": 5,
        "Phone": "(366) 967-0433",
        "City": "Dublin",
        "Name": "Cairo"
    }, {
        "ID": 16,
        "parentID": 11,
        "Phone": "(147) 708-7321",
        "City": "Rivière-du-Loup",
        "Name": "Mannix"
    }, {
        "ID": 17,
        "Phone": "(407) 519-9894",
        "City": "Roubaix",
        "Name": "Justine"
    }, {
        "ID": 18,
        "parentID": 14,
        "Phone": "(938) 793-5446",
        "City": "Eugene",
        "Name": "Dahlia"
    }, {
        "ID": 19,
        "parentID": 5,
        "Phone": "(425) 682-2189",
        "City": "Salisbury",
        "Name": "Irene"
    }, {
        "ID": 20,
        "parentID": 12,
        "Phone": "(351) 187-8200",
        "City": "Garaguso",
        "Name": "Trevor"
    }, {
        "ID": 21,
        "Phone": "(601) 944-5214",
        "City": "Pointe-au-Pic",
        "Name": "Iris"
    }, {
        "ID": 22,
        "parentID": 20,
        "Phone": "(479) 532-6127",
        "City": "Salt Lake City",
        "Name": "Fleur"
    }, {
        "ID": 23,
        "parentID": 19,
        "Phone": "(339) 973-1695",
        "City": "Meldert",
        "Name": "Hayley"
    }, {
        "ID": 24,
        "parentID": 11,
        "Phone": "(946) 766-1649",
        "City": "Corral",
        "Name": "Baker"
    }, {
        "ID": 25,
        "Phone": "(964) 413-7033",
        "City": "Joliet",
        "Name": "Leo"
    }, {
        "ID": 26,
        "parentID": 7,
        "Phone": "(898) 476-0059",
        "City": "Burntisland",
        "Name": "Rigel"
    }]
```

original data like this